# Gmail message = Noise proof, coming call - ringing sound

Tags: gmail, calls

I'm looking for a app that you can make the coming gmail message to give non sound but only vibration but when it comes to incoming call, you can hear the ringing sound.

Is there a app for android to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "noise proof"? It sounds like you're simply trying to silence Gmail's notifications, and I'm pretty sure Gmail's settings provide a way to do that, so you wouldn't need an app. If that's *not* what you're trying to do then I think it would be helpful if you could clarify.

Comment: is it better now

Comment: So, again, why are you looking for a separate app to do this? Doesn't Gmail have notification options in its settings? Is that not working the way you expect?